# How does the operator $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial w\partial\bar w}$ transform under a conformal change of coordinates?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, derivatives

Let $\omega$ be a complex coordinate. I am trying to figure out how the operator $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial w\partial\bar w}$ transforms under a conformal change of coordinate, i.e. for a smooth test function $f(\omega)$, if we let $w=w(z)$ be a conformal change of coordinate, then
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial w\partial\bar w}f(w)=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z\partial\bar z}(?)$$

**Attempt:**

We can directly write $$\frac{\partial}{\partial w}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial w}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}+\frac{\partial\bar z}{\partial w}\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar z}\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar w}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial\bar w}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}+\frac{\partial\bar z}{\partial\bar w}\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar z}$$
Note that $w=w(z)$ implies $\frac{\partial z}{\partial\bar w}=\frac{\partial\bar z}{\partial w}=0$. Hence
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial w}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial w}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar w}=\frac{\partial\bar z}{\partial\bar w}\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar z}$$
$$\implies\frac{\partial^2}{\partial w\partial\bar w}=(\frac{\partial z}{\partial w}\frac{\partial}{\partial z})(\frac{\partial\bar z}{\partial\bar w}\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar z})=\left|\frac{\partial z}{\partial w}\right|^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z\partial\bar z}$$
Consequently,
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial w\partial\bar w}f(w)=\left|\frac{\partial z}{\partial w}\right|^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z\partial\bar z}f(w(z))$$
Is this correct?

Comment: Looks correct to me. An easy way to test is by choosing an $f$ and a conformal map and see if the results match.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Can I say that $|\frac{\partial z}{\partial w}|^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z\partial\bar z}$ is the pullback of $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial w\partial\bar w}$?

Comment: From what I recall from geometry which was quite a while ago.. yes?